# Can I omit the EventTrigger.Actions?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I am using WPF with the MVVM Pattern and Prism, and I'm using InteractionRequests for showing dialogs.

When I define the InteractionTriggers and their actions, I define them like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
[Other event triggers]
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Raised" SourceObject="{Binding SomeConfirmationInteractionRequest}">
        <i:EventTrigger.Actions>
            <windowActions:DialogWindowAction />
        </i:EventTrigger.Actions>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Now I was checking my EventTriggers, and realized, I am missing one of the `<i:EventTrigger.Actions>` tags inside of the `<i:EventTrigger>`:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Raised" SourceObject="{Binding SomeConfirmationInteractionRequest}">
    <windowActions:DialogWindowAction />
</i:EventTrigger>
```

I was more confused that this part of my code worked, and there was no problem with it.

My question:

Why can it simply be omitted?

Can I just leave it out? Or does leaving the `EventTrigger.Actions` tag out change something that I haven't realized/experienced yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be safely omitted.

If you look at the `TriggerBase` class (up the inheritance tree of `EventTrigger`), you'll see it has an attribute `[ContentProperty("Actions")]`. This tells WPF to treat the `Actions` property as the direct child of the element in XAML.

This is widely used in WPF, e.g. `ContentControl`s have the `Content` property (so you can write `<Button><Image/></Button>` instead of `<Button><Button.Content><Image/></Button.Content></Button>`), `Panel`s have the `Children` property as their content, etc.

Comment: [ContentProperty("Actions")] - Awesome! That's why xaml has so many ways to describe the same thing, I didn't know! Thank you :)